# dynamically set navigation controller title

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm working with core data, and part of my app is very very similar to the default contacts app. There is an edit screen after a contact is in core data, and I would like to make the title: [insert contact name here] s information". I know I can set the title to just the core data entity attribute by doing: self.navigationController.title = _athletesFullName; (property for attribute under the entity "Athlete"). Is there any way I can do something like

```
self.navigationController.title = @"%@'s information",_athletesFullName; ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this code:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 's information",_athletesFullName];
```

Comment: First tried self.navigationController.navigationItem.title. Nothing. Then self.navigationController.title. Nothing. Finally, self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluations",_athletesFullName]; did it. Thanks Kirti!

Comment: self.title  working for me, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`self.navigationItem setTiltle:` is the normal way. The navigationItem is added by interface builder is you embed your viewcontroller in a navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of your navController, then you can change your navTitle as:

```
UINavigationController *navc  = (UINavigationController)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    navc.navigationItem.title = @"Yout Title";
```

OR

Try to use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Your Title";
```